# Is it feasible to use MVP or MVPC in game Development?

Tags: model-view-controller, user-interface, architecture, model

I am wondering if it is feasible for me to use MVP or MVPC in game development, if yes then how it could help me produce more confined output.

MGD

Answer (score 2):

In general, the MVC pattern doesn't *really* work for game development.  There's usually not enough difference between what are normally models, views, and controllers in games that it usually doesn't make sense to separate them out.  It's very hard to achieve the sort of separation needed to make a true "MVC" program.

That said, it's not entirely impossible.  There's an excellent set of answers about MVC in game development in this question: [Why are MVC & TDD not employed more in game architecture?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/why-are-mvc-tdd-not-employed-more-in-game-architecture)

Comment: thanks for the response then tell me what kind of architecture could be well utilized for 2D Mobile game development ... the suggestion will be welcomed !! :)